# How to map an array of object in react native

Tags: mapping, react-native, react-native-ios

I am currently getting data which is an array of objects from my local storage in following manner:

```
const [dataList, setDataList] = useState();
const getLocalItem = async () => {
    try {
      const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('somekey');
      const list = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
      setDataList(list);
      console.log("list: ", dataList);
      return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
    } catch (e) {
      // error reading value
    }
  }

<TouchableOpacity onPress={getLocalItem}>
    <Text>Get file</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Following is getting consoled:

```
list:  
{0: {…}, 1: {…}, default: Array(2)}
0: {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "optio reprehenderit", body: " molestiae ut ut quas "}
1: {userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse", body: " aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"}
default: (2) [{…}, {…}]
__proto__: Object
```

Now I am trying to map through this data to display it on my screen:

```
{
    dataList?.map(function (item, index) {
        return (
            <Text>{item.userId}</Text>
        );
    })
}
```

But I am getting error:

`dataList.map is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

The dataList is an object and not an array. You cannot map through objects. And that's why you're getting this error.

You can use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the value of object and consequently apply map on.

```
{Object.values(dataList).map(item => {
        return <Text>{item.title}</Text>;
      })}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `map` function can only be called on an **array** of values.

Solution:

```
[dataList]?.map(function (item, index) {
        return (
            <Text key={index}>{item.userId}</Text>
        );
    })
```

(also add a key to your child component when mapping).